# Find value from key in JSON Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How can i check which JSON value exist in JSON Array? Here are my solution:

```
var jsonArr = "[{"F_1":"c4024087","F_2":"9a565962","F_3":"23026","F_4":"John","F_5":"Doe"},{"F_1":"dbb88908","F_2":"bc6fd3bb","F_3":"19727","F_4":"Mike","F_5":"Long"}]"
```

Find the value:

```
var toFind = "9a565962";

var checkObj = jsonArr.find(o => o.F_2 == toFind );
  if (typeof checkObj === "undefined") {
    console.log("Value " + toFind + " not exists in Array. Do something!"); 
  } else (Object.keys(checkObj).length > 0) {
      console.log("Value " + toFind + " exists in Array. Do something else");
    }
```

Is this the best way to find a value in a array?

Comment: What do you mean by "best way" ?

Comment: Are there faster solutions or does my solution have performance issues with very large arrays?

Comment: You can look at this performance comparison of `find` and `for` loop https://jsperf.com/array-find-vs-for

Answer (score 0):

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents("/json/API.php");

$array = json_decode($jsondata,true);

foreach($array as $k=>$val):

if($id =! $val){   
 echo '<b>id: '.$k.'</b></br>';
    $keys = array_keys($val);
    foreach($keys as $key):
        echo '&nbsp;'.ucfirst($key).' = '.$val[$key].'</br>';
    endforeach;
endforeach;
}
```

Probably it will solve your problem Best Regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: That's a PHP answer on a JavaScript question?